# display text, then let it disappear after a minute

Tags: objective-c, ios, uilabel

I'd like to display a short warning message in an existing `UILabel` and then have it automatically disappear after a minute or so without having to pause the app (as in doing a loop or similar).

What's the best approach ?

Comment: Not familiar enough to post code or give a confident answer, but I suspect you can do something with Core Animation.  I'm thinking set the text, make it visible (transparency), and then set an animation so it will become invisible after a time.  If that meets your needs, you could even have it do something slick like fade out or slide in and out of the view.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use an NSTimer:

```
NSTimer* timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:60 target:self selector:@selector(hideLabel) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
```

And have a method `hideLabel` that hides the label, with `[myLabel setHidden:YES];` or something like that.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote this myself. It's pretty simple and it's probably what you are looking for.
Popup any UIView instance on top or bottom then disappear after a few seconds.

https://github.com/SaKKo/SKTipAlertView

Hope you find it useful.
cheers,

Answer (score -1):

Use UIAlertView (with no buttons) for popping up something interesting.

```
UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Title"
           message:@""
             delegate:self
          cancelButtonTitle:@""
          otherButtonTitles:nil];
[alertView show];
[alertView release];
```

Create an method for dismissing alertView after (say 2 seconds)

```
[self performSelector:@selector(byeAlertView:) withObject:alertView afterDelay:2];
```

Method for dismissing it...

```
-(void)byeAlertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView{
[alertView dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: This could be useful in some places, but I don't think it answers the question.  This won't appear on the existing UILabel as asked.  Also, while any processing being performed by the app won't be blocked, the UIAlertView is modal, and will prevent the user from doing anything with the app until it goes away.  I suspect he wants to have a less intrusive way to inform the user of an event but not get in their way.

Comment: thank you for the answer, but I try avoiding popups whenever possible. I find a UILabel a lot let obtrusive, but still very informative.

Comment: FML. I forgot about the UILabel